# HTTP 500 ERROR An exception occurred Symfony/EasyAdmin

Tags: postgresql, symfony, easyadmin

An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "genre_id" of relation "book" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL: Failing row contains (7, blabla, abababa, 0, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In inte..., 21/07/2007, null, null, null, null).

Have this error while writing a book data. I tried to enter the genre_id, the name of the genre but it doesn't work. The ID is generated automatically by Symfony so I don't understand how to avoid this to create a book data.

Precision : I made a ManyToOne relation between genre and book, in book entity.

Do you know how to avoid this error ?

My book entity file:

```
...
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $genre;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $date_de_parution;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Genre::class, inversedBy="livres")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $Genre;


[![genre table related to books][1]][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWQNR.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Genre is a required (`nullable=false`) foreign key. So it requires a Genre to be set when saving to the database.

If you want books to have NO Genre, you should be using a `nullable=true` Genre reference. Keep in mind that your getters/setters of Genre should also reflect this `null`able return.

```php
/**
 * @return Genre|null
 */
public function getGenre(): ?Genre   // See the questionmark (for php 7+ only)
{
    return $this->Genre;
}
```

[update - missed the EasyAdmin part]

When using admin generators, you should look for something like how to manage relations. It seems that EasyAdmin's documentation is not that great. Looking at [the demo application](https://github.com/EasyCorp/easyadmin-demo/blob/main/src/Controller/EasyAdmin/PostCrudController.php#L55) it seems there is an `AssociationField` field type, which can be used to reference relations.

Comment: I don't know if I didn't understand but if I want books to never be null and always have genre (which are already wrote in another related table see my edit question) how do I do ?

Comment: You have to add a Genre when creating a book. I missed the EasyAdmin part in your question.  When using admin generators, you should look for something like how to manage relations. After a quick look at the demo application codebase it seems there is an `AssociationField` field type when referencing relations. In your case: `AssociationField::new('genre')` which should be added to the `configureFields` method of the `BookController`.  Take a look here and search for `AssociationField` https://github.com/EasyCorp/easyadmin-demo/blob/main/src/Controller/EasyAdmin/PostCrudController.php